# Auth0 "Lock" for Swift Username-Password Login not working

Tags: ios, swift, auth0

I have set up a Swift App with the Auth0 Web Login and everything works fine. Then i have tried to implement the "Lock" login with the result that social media login works perfectly well, but i cannot login  via the username-password method.

On my Auth0 database, the signed-up user shows up (indicating that sign up of new username-passoword user actually work) and testing the login itself on the Auth0 Homepage works fine as well. Just when trying to login with the Lock widget, i get an error: "We're sorry, something went wrong when attempting to log in.". I also tried verifying the registered E-Mail, but that did not solve the issue either.
Any ideas, what might go wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After also pointing that issue out to Auth0/Lock support, a solution was found. Maybe this helps people, having the same problem: When using the Lock client inside some VC:

```
Lock
        .classic()
        .withOptions {
            $0.scope = "openid profile"
            $0.oidcConformant = true
            $0.logHttpRequest = true
        }
        .withStyle {
            $0.title = "App Name"
        }
        .onAuth { credentials in
            print("successful login")
        }
        .onError { error in
            print("Failed with error \(error)")
        }
        .present(from: self)
```

instead of the web login:

```
Auth0
.webAuth()
.audience("https://alienbash.eu.auth0.com/userinfo")
.start {
    switch $0 {
    case .failure(let error):
        // Handle the error
        print("Error: \(error)")
    case .success(let credentials):
        // Do something with credentials e.g.: save them.
        // Auth0 will automatically dismiss the hosted login page
        print("Credentials: \(credentials)")
    }

}
```

one has to make sure to change "Grant_Type" the Auth0 client settings to also allow the "Password" Grant. In order to do that, in your Auth0 client go to:

> Settings --> Advances Settings --> Grant Types

and make sure to check "Password as this checkmark is unchecked by default when creating a new Auth0 client and will be inevitable when using the "Lock" client.
[image]